# Flutter how to bring front widget

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

is there anyway that we can bring the widget front of the screen and let other widget behind the screen?, tried `Stack` widget but not working, I'm implementing a Google Maps using flutter `google_maps_flutter` library, see code below:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final size = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window).size;
final GoogleMapOverlayController controller =
    GoogleMapOverlayController.fromSize(
  width: size.width,
  height: size.height,
);

class GoogleMapView extends StatefulWidget {
  _GoogleMapViewState createState() => _GoogleMapViewState();
}

class _GoogleMapViewState extends State<GoogleMapView> {
  final mapController = controller.mapController;
  final Widget mapWidget = GoogleMapOverlay(controller: controller);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    GoogleMapController.init();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width,
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            mapWidget,
            new Container(
              height: 100.0,
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: new Text('Hey there!'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[controller.overlayController],
    );
  }
}
```

See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvwWO.png) which it should have a red color on top of the google map aligned in the top corner of the screen.  How to implement this using flutter `Stack` widget, I'm having problem with this since yesterday and couldn't find any solution, can anyone help me with this? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack works fine for that purpose, it's just that the Google Maps plugin is rendering a native view that can't yet be overlayed by something else.

You might want to follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73

See especially this comment https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73#issuecomment-417040742

Comment: I see thanks for the information @Günter Zöchbauer,  One more thing, is this is official Google Maps for flutter? just curious since I haven't read too much about the implementation.

Comment: Yes, the https://github.com/flutter/plugins repo contains the "official" Flutter plugins.

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer, I am having the similar situation now. It was working before but broken with the  flutter 3.0 version upgrade. I have logged a issue in stackoverflow. Do you have any clues for me. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72291539/flutter-stack-widget-always-shows-the-platformviewlink-android-widget-at-the-t