# Flutter Stack widget always shows the PlatformViewLink [Android widget] at the top

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-android

I have flutter screen, I am using a hosting android widget using PlatformViewLink for video player widget.

We designed a player widget with combination 2 widgets, 1st one is video widget and 2nd one is options widget.
We used Stack to display options widget on top of player widget.

Our code similar to the below.

```
Stack(
      children: [
      PlatformViewLink(       //Video widget
      viewType: 'video_view',
      ...
      ...
      ),
      MyOptionsOverlayWidget() //Overlay widget
      ])
```

It was working fine till yesterday. But today we upgraded flutter version to 3.0.
So now the player is showing but overlayoptions are hidden by the video widget and not accessable.

Can any one has idea to solve this. Please advice.

Below was the working player screen sample.

[image]